# Explicitly verifying a mocha expectation after it's been called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mocha.js, expectations, spinach

I am using `Mocha::Hooks#mocha_verify` in the `after_scenario` [spinach hook](https://github.com/codegram/spinach#hook-architecture) which works fine for some cases. However, there are many times when I want to verify an expectation after a value has been updated on a piece of data. For example,

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :checked, if: -> (record) { record.previous_changes.key?('checked_at') && record.checked_at? }

  def checked
    Bus.publish_at(checked_at + 1.day, 'checked', id: id)
  end
end
```

Right now I'm having to set the expectation before the ["act"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) part of the test runs so I have to do something like:

```
Bus.expects(:publish_at).with(
  instance_of(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone),
  'checked',
  has_entries(id: @my_model.id)
).once
```

The test data in `@my_model` still has `nil` `checked_at` because the "act" part of the test hasn't run yet, but I would like to verify that the first parameter is correct. I don't see a way to do this but it would be nice to be able to verify an invocation after the "act" part of the test like:

```
Bus.verify(:publish_at).with(
  @my_model.checked_at + 1.day,
  'checked',
  has_entries(id: @my_model.id)
).once
```